# How to reload resource from server after update during runtime Java web start?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I am trying to achieve the automatic update for my java web-start applicaiton. Logic: I am fetching the jnlp file from the server and comparing the timestamp with the current one. if there is difference then download the latest file and restart the application with javaws command. Now I have two problems. 1. I am not able to fetch the local jnlp file (because the location for jnlp file is different for different operating system as mentioned here 2. I am not able to find a graceful way to restart the application after killing the current running application. I would appreciate if there is any other graceful solution available. Thanks

I am trying to implement automatic update using java web start 
But i am facing the following issue  :
1)Not able to figure out a way to force/direct Java Web Start to check for updates in background when application is running.

2)Even,If I wrote a logic to check for updates manually in background thread , but then, I am not able to find a way to **restart** my application by running 
**my.jnlp** file.

following similar questions on my issue ,I figured out Java Web Start provide some implementation as [DownloadService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/DownloadService.html) which can be used to solve my issue.
But i didn't found any relevant example or pointer doc regarding utilisation of the [DownloadService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/DownloadService.html) implementation.

Please Help.